# is it possible to auto create dist folder when not exists using xelatex compile tex project

Tags: xetex

the xelatex compile output will automatic write some output in `content` folder, when compile in the root of project, there contains a `content` folder and it works fine. Now I tweak my command and add the `-output-directory` parameter like this:

```
 xelatex -output-directory=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Downloads/cquthesis/out/ main.tex
```

the out folder did not contains the sub-folder `content` make the compile failed. the error looks like:

```
! I can't write on file `content/introduction.aux'.
```

Is it possible to make the xelatex compile command auto create the `content` folder in the output new `out` folder? because all the compile process was automatcially running by robot. I can not created the content folder by hand one by one.

Comment: `-output-directory` creates more problems than it solves. personally I never use it, but the required structure is the same as the source structure, so your script can create it intially by doing a recursive copy of the source, or running `find` and creating the subdirectories